# What's 'it' in the sentence 'it is worth it'?

Tags: adjectives, it-its-itself, worth

> Rebooting your career is definitely worth **it**.

Actually, my question is not specific to this sentence. I don't get the word **it** in the use of **worth** in general as in this one:

> It is worth it.

If it were

> Rebooting your career is worth taking some risks.

it would be crystal clear to me.

Comment: Where have you seen "It is worth to know"?

Comment: Aside from a dummy pronoun in general. "worth it" means worth the *price* you'd pay, or the *dues* you'd pay metaphorically.

Comment: As for _worth_, it's part of the Commercial Transaction Frame, [like _value, cost,_ and _price_,](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) and uses senses local to that frame.

Comment: @KillingTime, you're right. My mistake. I had put it in the question just after a Google search without seeing it in a reliable source. I removed it from the question. Thank you.

Comment: _Worth it_ means 'worth [the trouble of] doing, a good idea' etc.

Comment: Is an answer about [dummy pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) like 'it' and 'there' appropriate here?

Comment: The first "it" is anaphoric. "Worth it" is an idiom, with "worth" as an adjective in predicative function with "it" as its meaningless complement.

Comment: While I closed this as a duplicate of what might as well be the opposite question (asking about the first "it"), the answers seem to explain both parts pretty well.